# How do you properly configure type = "both" on AppVeyor to not require user input?

Tags: r, install.packages, appveyor

Because a package (feather) for R 3.5.0 is only available from source, my current AppVeyor builds are failing.

I've determined that using `PKGTYPE: source` will fix the builds, however it takes about 5x as long since it's building all packages from source, when in reality it only needs to build one package from source. `PKGTYPE: both` results in the builds failing.

In RStudio, `install.packages(c("feather", "tidyr"), type = "both"))` will install tidyr from binary and feather from source, which is the behavior I want to replicate on AppVeyor. However it requires user input in the form of a popup asking the user if it should attempt to install from source. I assume this UI requirement is why using `PKGTYPE: both` fails.

Is there a way to not require user input to install packages from source when `type = "both"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can not require user input from `install.packages(..., type = "both")` by setting the `install.packages.compile.from.source` option to `"always"`. See: [How to not need user input for install.packages(type = "both")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510644/how-to-not-need-user-input-for-install-packagestype-both/51512013#51512013)

However, currently, R-AppVeyor uses `remotes::install_deps()`, which according to the man pages automatically switches `"both"` to `"binary"`, so the above option is moot, and `PKGTYPE: both` appears to work the same as `PKGTYPE: binary` for the AppVeyor yaml.

So, instead of using `PKGTYPE: both`, or building all packages, if you know which package needs to be built, you can do so by adding a call to Rscript in the AppVeyor yaml. I added the following to appveyor.yml to build feather from source, before the additional packages are loaded with the call to `install_deps`:

```
build_script:
    - Rscript -e install.packages('feather',type='source',repos='https://cran.rstudio.com')
    - travis-tool.sh install_deps
```

*Note, the second bullet already existed*