# How to not need user input for install.packages(type = "both")

Tags: r, user-input, install.packages

Normally, `install.packages(..., type = "both")` requires user input if there is a package that needs to be built from source.

For example (currently, with R 3.5.1), `install.packages(c("feather", "tidyr"), type = "both"))` will install tidyr from binary and feather from source, as long as there is a user to click "yes" when it gets to the feather install.

Is there a way to automatically click yes, or not require user input through some of the options to `install.packages()`?

*Note:* `install.packages(..., type = "source")` does not require user input, but it builds all packages, which is not the desirable behavior in this case.

Comment: Are you doing this from the command line, or from RStudio?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I'm using R-studio, but this occurs in the standard R GUI as well. And I'm in need of the answer for an install through AppVeyor if that matters at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `install.packages.compile.from.source` option can be set to `"always"` to install packages from source without prompting for UI. The default is `"interactive"`, which will prompt for user confirmation when using `type="both"`.

Solution:

```
options(install.packages.compile.from.source = "always")
install.packages(c("feather","tidyr"), type = "both")
```

Comment: Deleted my answer. This is much better.

Comment: Is the option setting valid for the live R session or we need to run it every time?

Comment: Btw, I think it is `options` and not `option`:
`options(install.packages.compile.from.source = "always")`

Comment: @nba2020 - it would be valid for the entire R session